# C# System.ComponentModel refuses to work at runtime

Tags: c#

I simply want to see if a string can be converted to any valid type using: `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).IsValid(value))` type is `System.Type` and value is `System.String`.

I get the following message at Runtime on the line that I call the aforementioned method: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Visual Studio also gives me the call stack and the first entry is, External Code.

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    MyProgram.Core.Extensions.CanCovertToValue(string) in Extensions.cs
    MyProgram.Core.Parser.IdentifyTokens(string[]) in Parser.cs
    Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

Here's the method it's used in:

```
public static bool CanCovertToValue(this string value)
        {
            foreach (Type type in Types)
            {
                if (System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).IsValid(value))
                {
                    if (type == typeof(string))
                    {
                        if (value.StartsWith("\"") && value.EndsWith("\""))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (type == typeof(Uri))
                    {
                        if (value.StartsWith("\"") && value.EndsWith("\""))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                    if (type == typeof(char))
                    {
                        if (value.StartsWith("'") && value.EndsWith("'"))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return false;
        }
```

The problem turned out to be that I was trying to iterate through custom structs of a referenced library that references a different version of Newtonsoft.Json. It works perfectly fine with built in C# types.

Comment: What are those types? And also, of course it's going to happen at runtime, that's reflection code.

Comment: It's just a list of the usual primitives, bool, int, float, void, Uri, DateTime, TimeSpan as well as some custom struct types from a referenced library.

Comment: Does that referenced library reference Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Okay I feel very silly now. The problem was that the referenced library was technically dlls from a Unity game and I guess it got upset for some reason? When I commented out the list of structs the game uses, it worked without a problem. I imagine to test out the custom types, I'll need to have the game running and my library loaded as a mod rather than testing it outside of the game without having to relaunch it over and over to test it. Thank you very much! Please make a main comment so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: Yes, the game does reference Newtonsoft.Json, a different version too. I don't suppose there's a way to force it to use the one System.ComponentModel likes?

Comment: You can try an redirect dll's but I am not sure if System.ComponentModel uses any 3rd Party Lib's. Either way you can take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element